# Systemd activates constantly heats up and slows down my computer

Tags: systemd

In both Kubuntu 18.04 and Kubuntu 20.04, systemd constantly activates, heats up my computer and slows it down.
I have an Intel Core i7-9750H and it is not for systemd to consume so much CPU resources.
I open the KSysGuard system monitor and see systemd consuming up to 45% CPU, I cannot kill the service because it is a parent process.
I have read that systemd is a daemon that makes more superficial processes interact with the linux kernel.
I think the solution to this issue is configuration, but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: I found the answer but as paradoxically in AskUbuntu it is about not answering anything and they closing questions without answering them, thats why I do not share the answer to this problem either.

Comment: What makes hate and contempt to a distribution is not the Distrubucion itself, but unpleasant people surrounding the distribution.

Comment: When you ask a question where you don't understand fundamental points, for example what systemd is, you shouldn't wonder when people think not in a positive way about your question. You are supposed to do some research by yourself. What are you doing now? Trash talking and being a dick by not publising your research efforts and making this community as weak as you don't like it either. Btw. systemd is probably not slowing down your system, but a faulty daemon/service.

Comment: Was an application that consumed many resources.
How do you know that I did not investigate before asking?
Dicks only respond when they read something they don't like, these dicks blame others for being dicks.
You should ask yourself first what others think of the answers you give
PRACTICE WHAT YOU PREACH BEFORE YOUR DICK RECOMENDATIONS!!!... OK??? Dicks come to false conclusions without evidence